# Update an HTML tag innerHTML without line break

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a variable from javascript to HTML page. After the script is executed, it adds a new line (before the second sentence). What I want to do is to update the HTML inside the `<div>` tag only and continue the line without any break.

```
    <html> 
    <body> 
    <p> Some text here <div id="my-id">my text</div>. Other text here.</p>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("my-id").innerHTML = "Add my text here";
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try changing your internal ```<div>``` to a ```<span>```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<div>` is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) by default.

You can override this with CSS, but you're better off using a `<span>` instead, which is not a block-level element by default.

```
<span id='my-id'></span>
```

If you absolutely must use a div, you can use inline style:

```
<div style='display:inline' id='my-id'></div>
```

Or you can define it in a stylesheet:

```
div#my-id { display:inline; }
```